# Update post meta within save_post action

Tags: posts, post-meta, actions, advanced-custom-fields, save-post

I'm currently trying to update a post's meta value within the save_post action. The problem with this is that it gets overwritten immediately. I've been banging my head on this problem for several hours and can't get it to work. Is there a way to update the meta without it being overwritten?

My code is below

```
add_action( 'save_post_promo', 'update_promo_tag_id', 10, 1 );
function update_promo_tag_id( $post_id ) { update_field( 'one_time_tag_id', 'updated!', $post_id ); }
```

Comment: When you say it gets overwritten, it gets overwritten to what? What's your final post meta value?

Comment: It's empty. There's previously no value in the field.

Comment: Ok - and you are certain the code runs at all? Do you have any other plugins or code that maybe use a filter on custom field values?

Comment: I'm sure the code runs, if I hardcore the Post ID of a different post it runs. I have no other code that fires on save.

Comment: Weird - maybe this can help? https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/update_field-on-publish-2/

Comment: Thanks, but the problem isn't ACF (I've also tried the standard update_post_meta function.) The issue is that the new value is being written but then immediately overwritten by the save function.

Comment: What happens if you just use `save_post` instead of your current hook.

Comment: I haven't tried that, as the only difference is that I would have to add a conditional to my code to check for the post type. My current hook is the same action but with the added custom post type.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that the `$post_id` parameter passed to via the `save_post_$post_type` hook is *not* the same `$post_id` as the original post - it's the `$post_id` of the temporary post that's created when you edit a post.

To confirm this:

```
add_filter( 'pre_post_update', 'wpse_pre_post_update', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'save_post', 'wpse_save_post', 10, 1 );

function wpse_pre_post_update( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
  echo $post_id . '<br>';
}
function wpse_save_post( $post_id ) {
  echo $post_id;
  wp_die();
}
```

If you're trying to add a new post, then pre_post_update hook doesn't fire and WP will die before taking you to edit screen. Comment out the `wp_die()` line, then click the "Add New" link. Now, uncomment out the `wp_die()` and save the post. Two non-identical IDs should be output before WP dies.

The first ID is the ID of the actual post.
The second ID is the ID of the temporary post.

It doesn't really make sense to me why WordPress does it this way, and I have no idea if it's always been like this. But it has this behavior for me running a fresh install of WP 4.7.3.

Unless for some reason you **need** to update the option after the post is saved, I'd use the `pre_post_update` hook instead.

```
add_filter( 'pre_post_update', 'update_promo_tag_id', 10, 3 );
function update_promo_tag_id( $post_id, $post, $update ) { 
  if( 'promo' !== $post->post_type ) {
    return $post_id;
  } 
  update_field( 'one_time_tag_id', 'updated!', $post_id );
  return $post_id;
}
```